# Modifying a model just before SaveChanges()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, entity-framework-4.1

*This is an ultra-simplified version of my problem but it gets straight to the point.*

I have this model

```
public int QuestionId { get; set; }
public string QuestionText { get; set; }
public string AnswerText { get; set; }
```

Now, imagine I want to modify the AnswerText to "blah blah" just before SaveChanges() in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Question question)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        question.AnswerText = "blah blah"

        db.Questions.Add(question);                
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    return View(question);
}
```

**This works as expected**.

Now, in place of *public string AnswerText { get; set; }* I want a list of answers:

```
public List<string> AnswersText { get; set; }
```

And I want to manually add answers just before SaveChanges():

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Question question)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        question.AnswersText = new List<string>();
        question.AnswersText.Add("blah1");
        question.AnswersText.Add("blah2");
        question.AnswersText.Add("blah3");

        db.Questions.Add(question);                
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    return View(question);
}
```

What I get is weird: My question is correctly added to the context but the list of answers is always empty. I don't know what to do, it seems such a simple task to me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is 'AnswersText' an entity object itself? if that's the case you will need to add those to the context as well before saving.

Comment: No, AnswersText is just a List object in the model.

Comment: How would you think the answers should be stored in the database? There is the key to your problem. `question.AnswersText` mus be a navigation property to `AnswerText` entities.

Comment: Can't ASP.NET MVC just store a List of strings inside an entity? [Note: if I create the list directly in the constructor of my Entity, it is correctly stored!)

Comment: It's not an MVC issue, it's an EF persistance issue, what DB field type is a 'List<string>'? Your persistence mechanism needs to know how to store the entity and it can't store collection in that way unless the collection is defined as a related entity. Think about the chance that the List has 1 record, or 4000000 records? how would the db store those? it needs a related table to hold a collection.

Comment: It is even not EF issue. It is not understanding to core concepts of used technologies.

Comment: Ok, it's obviously my fault. But I was confident it was a simple feature supported by the technology (other web MVC frameworks I tried support this). Just the end the discussion, I'm curious to know why creating a list of strings directly in the constructor of the Entity works fine and my list is correctly stored.

Comment: It can do it, you just need to add a related table to store the list of answer text.
How is the AnswersText property defined on your Questions entity?

Comment: Just like a simple List property:   public List<string> AnswersText {get; set;}    and in the constructor:   AnswersText = new List<string>();  AnswersText.Add("one"); AnswersText.Add("two");

Comment: I mean, how is that property defined in your .edmx file? specifically in the Designer.cs file?

Comment: Ok, I have no .edmx files. I'm using CodeFirst to generate models.

Comment: I think what you'd need to do in that case would be to define a class 'Answer' with perhaps a couple of properties, 'Id' and 'Text' perhaps and then make your Question class define it's AnswersText Property as public List<Answer> AnswersText { get; set; }. This way I think code first should be able to work out that it needs to create a seperate entity to model the AnswersText property as a collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect entity framework to have a List property and know how to store that. You need to create a Answer entity and use that instead:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }

    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

now in Question:

```
public class Question 
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

It will store questions and their answers as a separate table. Each answer to a single question will get its own individual row.

Comment: I should have moved my comment to an answer! :P

Comment: Thank you, Dismissile. Hehe, you should totally deserve the accepted answer, dougajmcdonald! Anyway, my problem isn't still solved. I mean... I have tried with this new Entity to insert a list during creation (http://pastebin.com/R7sfVQyx) but the result is the same. [Note: I had to use List in place of IEnumerable because now I can use @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Answers[0]) in my View to see the contents). This doesn't work. I can't believe it is so hard to create a List of objects from a form and save them in an Entity. It should be a basic task o_O